# Remove ns0 from XML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an XML file where I would like to edit certain attributes. I am able to properly edit the attributes but when I write the changes to the file, the tags have a strange "ns0" added onto them. How can I get rid of this? This is what I have tried and have been unsuccessful. I am working in Python and using lxml.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree
from lxml import etree, objectify
frag_xml_tree = ET.parse(xml_name)
frag_root = frag_xml_tree.getroot()

for e in frag_root: 
    for elem in frag_root.iter(e):
        elem.attrib[frag_param_name] = update_val
    etree.register_namespace("", "http://www.w3.org/2001")
    frag_xml_tree.write(xml_name)
```

However, when I do this, I only get the error `Invalid tag name u''`. I thought this error came up if the xml tags started with digits but that is not the case with my xml. I am really stuck on how to proceed. Thanks

Comment: What XML library are you using?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I have updated the post to include the information. thanks!

Comment: Please post your XML.  `ns0` is almost certainly a namespace prefix, and you probably don't actually need to remove it.

Comment: Thank you kjhughes! you were right. I was using the wrong namespace

Answer (score 20):

Actually the way to do it seemed to be a combination of two things.

1. The import statement is `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`
2. `ET.register_namespace("", NAMESPACE)` is the correct call, where NAMESPACE is the namespace listed in the input xml, ie the url after xmlns.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the corrected code using only `xml.etree.ElementTree` instead of `lxml`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
frag_xml_tree = ET.parse(xml_name)
frag_root = frag_xml_tree.getroot()

for e in frag_root: 
    for elem in frag_root.iter(e):
        elem.attrib[frag_param_name] = update_val
    ET.register_namespace("", "http://www.w3.org/2001")
    frag_xml_tree.write(xml_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

the following snippet removes the presence of ns0 throughout the xml file

for i in range (0,len(list(root))):

```
print(root[i])
ET.register_namespace("",NAMESPACE)
```

tree.write('TP_updated2.xml',xml_declaration=True,method='xml',encoding="utf8",default_namespace=None)

NAMESPACE = the url after the xmlns