# Python add new element by xml ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Info xmlns="BuildTest">
<RequestDate>5/4/2020 12:27:46 AM</RequestDate>
</Info>
```

I want to add a new element inside the `Info` tag.

Here is what I did.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('example.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
ele = ET.Element('element1')
ele.text = 'ele1'
root.append(ele)
tree.write("output.xhtml")
```

Output

```
<ns0:Info xmlns:ns0="BuildTest">
<ns0:RequestDate>5/4/2020 12:27:46 AM</ns0:RequestDate>
<element1>ele1</element1></ns0:Info>
```

Three questions:

1. The `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` is missing.
2. The namespace is wrong.
3. The `whitespace` of the new element is gone.

I saw many questions related to this topic, most of them are suggesting other packages.
Is there any way it can handle properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processing instructions are not considered XML elements. Just Google [are processing instructions part of an XML](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIL793IL793&sxsrf=ALeKk03wDinZmiYQxAcjeAsrnE34NDpVCA%3A1588892717103&ei=LZS0XuDlBYSR1fAPo7WYiAc&q=are%20processing%20instructions%20part%20of%20an%20XML&oq=are%20processing%20instructions%20part%20of%20an%20XML&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQR1CfxAFYucoBYMHSAWgAcAF4AIABgwGIAYYFkgEDMC41mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwigsPTP7qLpAhWESBUIHaMaBnEQ4dUDCAw&uact=5), and the first result states:

> **Processing instructions** are markup, but they're not elements.

Since the package you are using is literally called `ElementTree`, you can reasonably expect its objects to be a trees of elements. If I remember correctly, DOM compliant XML packages can support non-element markup in XML.

For the namespace issue, the answer is in stack overflow, at [Remove ns0 from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708658/remove-ns0-from-xml) - you just have to register the namespace you specified in the top element of your document. The following worked for me:

```
ET.register_namespace("", "Buildtest")
```

As for the whitespace - the new element does not have any whitespace. You can assign to the `tail` member to add a linefeed after an element.

Comment: The XML declaration is a special kind of processing instruction that is easily added. Just
use `tree.write("output.xhtml", xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")`.

Comment: @mzjn - thanks, I learned something new. I never bothered with processing instructions, as all my XML usage was always in case where my programs were both the producers and consumers of the XMLs.